# Maven Grouping Dependencies without installing pom

Tags: maven, maven-2, module, dependency-management

I have a maven project which has multiple profiles and lots of dependencies which are specific to each of those profiles.  The current solution to clean this up works by creating an intermediate dependency pom for each profile which groups the dependencies together as described here in 3.6.1: http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-pom-best-practice.html  Each of these dependency grouping poms lives in their own svn project and is build and deployed as a separate jenkins job.

The problem is that these poms, and the dependencies within them change and are released often and it has become difficult to maintain.  Ideally, I would like all of the dependency management to live under one svn project and one build.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you give a more detailed examples of the situation, cause i'm not sure what you mean by "released often..". The other question which comes to my mind is: Why do you have multiple dependency groupding pom? can you give an example how you are using them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Maven Release Plugin did what we needed.

Answer (score 0):

As khmarbaise writes, it would help with more information and an example.

However, just answering your actual question, how to get all your depenency grouping poms as one project and one build. It sound as if a [multi module project](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule.html) with each module being one of your "dependency grouping pom" projects would be what you are looking for.